# Weyl's asymptotic law on the compact segment $[0,a]$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, laplacian

In the Matt Stevenson's article ([Weyl's law](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/weyl_law.pdf)), we have : $$N(\lambda) = \# \{k \in \mathbb{N} : \lambda_k < \lambda \} = \# \left\{k \in \mathbb{N} : \left(\frac{k \pi}{a}\right)^2 < \lambda \right\} = \max \left\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k < \frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}\right\} \sim \frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}.$$ Could anyone is able to give me an explicit formula for $\max \left\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k < \frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}\right\}$? I struggle trying to find why the Weyl's law for a bounded line is true.

Comment: Depending what boundary conditions you have, etc., the eigenfunctions are exponentials or sines and cosines or... so the eigenvalues are basically $-n^2$ for integers $n$ (with minor variations depending...). Then Weyl's "law" is immediate. Is this the question?

Comment: @paulgarrett For you the Weyl's law is immediate, but not for me. I want to know why $\max \left\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k < \frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}\right\} \sim \frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}$

Comment: For the case of matching endpoint values, so it's the circle, the eigenfunctions are $x\to e^{inx}$, with eigenvalues $-n^2$.

Comment: You don't help me very much... Here our eigenvalues are $\lambda_k = (\frac{k \pi}{a})^2$. Why in a complete answer $\max \left\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k < \frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}\right\} \sim \frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}$?

Comment: Count integers less than a given bound...

Comment: Does $\max \left\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k < \frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}\right\} = \lfloor{\frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}} \rfloor$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Perhaps you were over-thinking this. No obligation to be so formulaic...

Comment: Now, why $\lfloor{\frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}} \rfloor \sim \frac{a \sqrt{\lambda}}{\pi}$ ?

Comment: It differs by less than 1... ?!? You are over-thinking this...